# What is the difference between Quadtree and PR-Quadtree?

Tags: data-structures, quadtree

Well, obviously Point Region Quadtree is a kind of Quadtree, where each splits data into quadrants. From what I've read, I can't see any differences between them. So: **What is the main difference between a Quadtree and a PR-Quadtree? Is there any advantage of one over the other?**

Comment: The principle of a quadtree is always to split the area into 4 quadrants, which will be the four children of the current node. Two questions arose: 1) when to stop dividing? 2) what's on a leaf? For a point-region quadtree, the leaf contains the list of points in the area corresponding to the leaf. Other types of quadtrees might contain different information.

Comment: @Stef Does that contradict what is said in Samet H. book (The design and analysis of spatial data structures): "A quadrant  contain at most one data point"?

Comment: I haven't read this book, but I'm guessing it takes "quadtree" to mean "the specific definition of quadtree we use in this book", whereas other people might say "let's call 'quadtree' all variations on the quadtree concept" and be more permissive on what qualifies as a quadtree.